# jQuery blocking ajax post

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, forms, contact-form

Im trying to have a form do a post using ajax method it is getting blocked by jquery line:7845

xhr.send( options.hasContent && options.data || null );

how can i fix this, keeps omiting ' send.php 404 not found '

send.php is in inside js folder here is my code for [php file](http://codepad.org/LWEaFhfB)

```
$('#contact').submit(function(e){
    e.preventDefault() 
if(!$('#contact').valid())
    return false;

$('#submit').fadeOut(200,function(){
    $('.sending').fadeIn(200);
});

$.ajax({
    url: 'js/send.php',
    type: 'post',
    data: {name:$("input[name='name']").val(),
           email:$("input[name='email']").val(),
           comments:$("textarea[name='comments']").val(),
          },

    success: function(data) {


        if(data==1)
        {
            $('.sending').html('Sent Successfully Thank You!');
            $('#contact').fadeOut(500);

            $("#contact input:not(#submit)").val('');
            $('#contact textarea').val('');

            txt_name = null;
        }
        else alert("error sending");
    },
    error:function(err)
    {
        alert("error sending");
    }
}); });
```

Comment: where is your send.php file saved?

Comment: `send.php` needs to be in your `js` folder for this to work. We also need to see `send.php`.

Comment: here is my send.php http://codepad.org/LWEaFhfB

Comment: `url: 'js/send.php'` -- may be a typo. Probably you wouldn't store a PHP file in the js folder

Comment: i have tried placing the send.php in the root of the website folder, does not seem to work gives me same error 'line:7845 404 error'